# Should Nifi's ConnectWebSocket get messages from a socket.io websocket server?

Tags: socket.io, apache-nifi

Is it possible for a nifi processor to get messages from a socket.io websockert server with ConnectWebSocket processor? or should I implement my own nifi processor in order to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own processor.